# LaTeX arev package and nonfunctioning nmid macro

Tags: arev

I just installed the latest texlive distribution on my MacBook.
I noticed one thing that doesn't work.
If I use the arev package, then $a \nmid b$ does not work.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}

$a \nmid b$

$a \mid b$

\end{document}
```

pdflatex on this file just produces nothing where I expect a negated
divides symbol.  The log file shows that even though this is texlive2016,
the arev package is old -- in fact, the same version that I was using earlier. So it seems that there must be some font or something that is missing.

Comment: Welcome! I guess a limitation of `arev`. It would be better if it warned you though, that the character is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  But the thing is, all of this worked on an older latex installation.  arev declares nmid as  \DeclareMathSymbol{\nmid}           {\mathrel}{mathdesignA}{"2D}

Comment: It maps to a different `\mathchar` than `amssymb` does, though. And apparently, the wrong one. (It might need to be different - that isn't necessarily wrong, I don't think.)

Comment: OK, I tried both of those "direct mappings". On my installation, 352D results in a Computer Modern nmid, which is OK, but doesn't really have the right "look". 362D results in nothing at all. I'm looking for a warning, but I don't see anything. I'm wondering if may latex distro has all its fonts set up correctly.

Comment: No. It is not your installation. I get the missing character, too.

Comment: And it's not just nmid...all the symbols declared in arev/ams-mdbch.sty are No-ops.  And they didn't used to be...something is amiss.

Comment: On my old texlive 2011 it all works fine.  I just double checked...the same code generates the right PDF

Comment: Could be. arev has not been updated for 12 years.  If I can't locate this person, is there an easy fix? I kind of rely heavily on arev...it's shame it seems to be unmaintained.  That said, for the legacy latex that uses it, I could perhaps switch to the older distro, which I could copy over to my new machine...hopefully...

Comment: I just sent him an email...we'll see.

Comment: You need to determine first if the problem is in `arev` or `mathdesign`. I'm too tired right now to trace things through properly. But see if you can load the fonts and get the symbols using `mathdesign`.

Comment: Definitely `arev`. `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` works as expected, at least.

Comment: It is marked as maintained on CTAN - not unmaintained.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be loading `amssymb`, because the symbols are already provided by `arev`.

### Revised answer

However, a change in `mathdesign` between TeX Live 2012 and TeX Live 2013 was not reflected in `ams-mdbch.sty`, which is part of the `arev` distribution.

You can fix it by redefining manually the symbols that were removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev}

%% fix the bug in ams-mdbch.sty
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mdbchbmb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mdbchbmb}{b}{n}{<-> s*[0.96]mdbchbmb}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{U}{mdbchbmb}{b}{n}

    \DeclareMathSymbol{\lvertneqq}    {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"00}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\gvertneqq}    {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"01}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nleq}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"02}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ngeq}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"03}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nless}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"04}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ngtr}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"05}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nprec}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"06}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsucc}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"07}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\lneqq}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"08}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\gneqq}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"09}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nleqslant}    {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"0A}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ngeqslant}    {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"0B}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\lneq}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"0C}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\gneq}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"0D}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\npreceq}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"0E}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsucceq}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"0F}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\precnsim}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"10}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\succnsim}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"11}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\lnsim}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"12}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\gnsim}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"13}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nleqq}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"14}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ngeqq}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"15}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\precneqq}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"16}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\succneqq}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"17}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\precnapprox}  {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"18}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\succnapprox}  {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"19}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\lnapprox}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"1A}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\gnapprox}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"1B}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsim}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"1C}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ncong}        {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"1D}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\diagup}       {\mathord}{mathdesignB}{"1E}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\diagdown}     {\mathord}{mathdesignB}{"1F}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varsubsetneq}   {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"20}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varsupsetneq}   {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"21}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsubseteqq}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"22}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsupseteqq}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"23}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\subsetneqq}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"24}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\supsetneqq}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"25}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varsubsetneqq}  {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"26}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varsupsetneqq}  {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"27}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\subsetneq}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"28}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\supsetneq}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"29}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsubseteq}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"2A}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nsupseteq}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"2B}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nparallel}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"2C}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nmid}           {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"2D}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nshortmid}      {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"2E}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nshortparallel} {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"2F}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nvdash}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"30}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nVdash}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"31}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nvDash}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"32}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nVDash}         {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"33}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ntrianglerighteq}{\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"34}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ntrianglelefteq}{\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"35}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ntriangleleft}  {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"36}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\ntriangleright} {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"37}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nleftarrow}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"38}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nrightarrow}    {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"39}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nLeftarrow}     {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"3A}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nRightarrow}    {\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"3B}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nLeftrightarrow}{\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"3C}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\nleftrightarrow}{\mathrel}{mathdesignB}{"3D}
%% end of fix

\begin{document}
$a \nmid b$

$a \mid b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Original answer

You shouldn't be loading `amssymb`, because the symbols are already provided by `arev`.

With a few exceptions, though. Here is the font table for `mdbchbma`

[image]

that should provide the `\nmid` symbol which is set up by

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nmid}{\mathrel}{mathdesignA}{"2D}
```

But, as you see in the font table, there is no glyph in that position and, indeed, the log file for your example has

```
Missing character: There is no - in font mdbchbma!
```

(the hyphen has ASCII code `"2D`).

You can get a decent substitute for `\nmid`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\highnot}{\mathrel}{mathdesignA}{"7D}
\renewcommand{\nmid}{%
  \mathrel{\mspace{-4mu}}%
  \highnot
  \mathrel{\mspace{4mu}}%
  \mid
}

\begin{document}

$a \nmid b$

$a \mid b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Shorter and lower:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\highnotsymbol}{\mathrel}{mathdesignA}{"7D}
\renewcommand{\nmid}{%
  \mathrel{\mspace{-2.5mu}}%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\highnot\relax}%
  \mathrel{\mspace{2.5mu}}%
  \mid
}
\newcommand{\highnot}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
  \fi\fi
  \highnotsymbol
}

\begin{document}
$a \nmid b$

$a \mid b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! However, I want to stress that everything worked just fine in texlive2011.  In fact, because I'm under some time constraints, I "solved" my problem by copying the old texlive2011 over to my new machine, along with the packaging info that allowed me to switch to this as my default. Now everything works again. However, this is not much of a solution...

Comment: So the questions are: (1) Why did those glyphs exist in 2011 and not 2016? arev itself has not changed at all.  (2) How to fix this more generally? I have a lot of legacy latex code that uses arev, and I would prefer not to fix this symbol by symbol.  Since this glyphs existed in 2011, there must be a way to get them in 2017...right???

Comment: @Victor Indeed! A change in `mathdesign` wasn't accompanied by a corresponding change in `arev`. Now I see better the situation.

Comment: @Victor Answer thoroughly revised.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much!! That is just the kind of hack I figured would do it...but it was well above my paygrade!! I will try it out...