# Not exists in with arev?

Tags: fonts, symbols, amsmath, amssymb, arev

I want to use the arev font for math. I noticed that the `\nexists` symbol does not render properly. Is it possible for me to use this font while having access to any special symbols that may be missing with the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from @user94293 establishes the problem. The correct answer, I guess, would be to manually define the missing symbols in arev including `nexists` using either @egreg's or @Mico's answers. I ended up just changing the font to newtxsf which is not missing symbols (to my knowledge) and looks alright to me.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in `arev`. The package, at some point, loads `ams-mdbch.sty`, where we find, at line 160

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nexists}        {\mathord}{mathdesignA}{"40}
```

However, the symbol font *doesn't* have a “not exists” symbol at that slot, but a circle. The loaded symbol font is supposed to mirror `AMSb` from `amssymb`, but it is definitely different from it.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362735/4427 for more symbols to fix.

Anyway, borrowing `\nexists` from `amssymb` is not a choice: here is the output with the borrowed symbol next to `\exists` from `arev`:

[image]

A solution might be to construct the symbol from a slash and `\exists`, but just superimposing them doesn't work. So my strategy is to

1. scale up the slash vertically by 10%;
2. scale down the slash horizontally by 20%;
3. raise the scaled slash to be vertically centered with respect to `\exists`.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\scalebox' macro

\let\nexists\relax % undefine the existing macro

\makeatletter 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nexists}{\mathord{\mathpalette\nexists@\relax}}

\newcommand{\nexists@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\nexists@slash{#1}}% for the bounding box
  \ooalign{\hidewidth\nexists@slash{#1}\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\exists$\cr}%
}
\newcommand{\nexists@slash}[1]{\raisebox{0.02\height}{\scalebox{0.8}[1.1]{$#1/$}}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$\exists\nexists$

$\scriptstyle\exists\nexists$

$\scriptscriptstyle\exists\nexists$

\medskip

{\Large$\nexists$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(modified the answer to make `\nexists` work in all math styles)

The macro `\nexists` defined below may be used in all of TeX's "math styles" -- `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{arev}
\let\nexists\relax % undefine the existing macro

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683452/5001 
% for the inspiration for the following code.
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\scalebox' macro
\makeatletter 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nexists}{%
   \mathchoice{\@nexists{\f@size}}{\@nexists{\f@size}}
              {\@nexists{\sf@size}}{\@nexists{\ssf@size}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@nexists}[1]{%
   \scalebox{\fpeval{(#1)/(\f@size)}}{\@@nexists}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@@nexists}{%
   \ooalign{\kern1.15pt\raise0.5pt\hbox{/}\cr$\exists$}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
$\exists$ $\nexists$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I really appreciate it. Are there other limitations/missing symbols in arev? Is there a similar math font that simply contains all symbols that one would normally expect, out of the the box?

Comment: @user41177 - You're most welcome. By the way, no font package contains "all" symbols.

Comment: I guess I mean one that can render all the symbols in amssymb.

Comment: @user41177 - Sorry, I don't have an answer to your follow-up question. Please consider posting a *new query*.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362714/